# Celery create multiple tasks from the same function

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I want to create multiple celery tasks from the same function, and they will differ in the parameters that I pass to the task decorator. Let's say I want to set different timeouts for paid and free account in my system.

I was expecting that applying the task decorator in the following way will do the trick:

```
def _update(x, y):
    ...    

update_free = task(soft_time_limit=300, time_limit=305)(_update)

update_paid = task(time_limit=1800)(_update)
```

But I see in the log that neither `update_paid` nor `update_free` are registered as tasks. Instead for some reason `_update` is registered as a task.

I don't why celery/django-celery does this, seem to be quite obscure to me.
Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Celery's `task` decorators uses the decorated function's name when registering the task, and this name is set to "_update" when the function is defined:

```
>>> def _update(x, y):
...     pass
... 
>>> _update.__name__
  > '_update'
>>> update2 = _update
>>> update2.__name__
  > '_update'
```

You can specify the name of the task in the decorator though:

```
update_free = task(name='update_free', soft_time_limit=300, time_limit=305)(_update)
update_paid = task(name='update_paid', time_limit=1800)(_update)
```